# Generating SOAP message with MTOM using php class extending SoapClient

Tags: php, soap, mtom

I created a class that extends SoapClient and overrides the __doRequest() function in order to be able to add an attachement to an external webserver that uses MTOM.

Basically, before calling the parent::__doRequest(), I edit the first parameter $request in order to add the MTOM part. My problem is that I get the "Error reading XMLStreamReader".

I'm not sure if it's because my generated message has mistakes or if the SoapClient::__doRequest() detects non-xml part and throws the soapfault.

Here is my generated soap message :

```
    Content-Type: multipart/related; boundary=MIMEBoundary4A7AE22984E7738034;
type="application/xop+xml"; start="<0.09BC7F4BE2E4L7EF1B@example.org>";
start-info="text/xml; charset=utf-8"


--MIMEBoundary2013-04-24_0
content-type: application/xop+xml; charset=utf-8; type="application/soap+xml;"
content-transfer-encoding: binary
content-id: <0.09BC7F4BE2E4L7EF1B@example.org>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1{endpoint} xmlns:ns2="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd"><SOAP-ENV:Header>
        <wsse:Security SOAP-ENV:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
            <wsse:UsernameToken>
                <wsse:Username>{username}</wsse:Username>
                <wsse:Password>{password}</wsse:Password>
            </wsse:UsernameToken>
        </wsse:Security></SOAP-ENV:Header><SOAP-ENV:Body><ns1:creerDepot/><param1>depot2013-04-24_0</param1><param2></param2></SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>


--MIMEBoundary2013-04-24_0
content-type: application/octet-stream
content-transfer-encoding: binary
content-id: <2013-04-24_0>


--MIMEBoundary2013-04-24_0--{file}
```

Can someone tell me if my problem come from my generated message that contains errors or if it comes from the __doRequest() that doesn't want to send it?

Comment: I know this is likely WAAAY too late, but is your {file} marker in the correct place? I think that should be before the closing boundary